# Laravel blade, is this authorized?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Using Laravel 6, I would like to display the title of a page dynamically ('NEW' or 'UPDATE') in a view. However, it is always 'Create School' which is displayed. When I debug, $school->id does not contain 'new' (but an UUID). Is this the best way to render a dynamic title?

```
@section('title', $school->id === 'new' ? 'Create school' : 'Update school')
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function create()
{
    $school = new School();
    $school->id = 'new';
    $school->country_id = 'FR';
    
    return view('/school/form', ['school' => $school]);
}

public function edit(School $school)
{
    return view('/school/form', ['school' => $school]);
}
```

When I return the view (it's the same view for create and edit), I send either an empty school or a school. In the view, I would like to display 'NEW' or 'UPDATE' only with the test of the `$school->id.`

Comment: Why do you expect that id to contain "new" ? Can you send a sample data?

Comment: First of all you need to print_f($school) and what you get output any data getting from console side..?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like below

```
@section('title)

    {{ $school->id === 'new' ? 'Create school' : 'Update school' }}

@stop
@section('othersection)
@endsection
```

and in your controller under `create`
 method i guess you need to call `save()` method. Perhaps you need depend upon you need or not. i just want to mention

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset()` function. When try create that case not need pass `$school` variable

```
@section('title', isset($school) ? 'Create school' : 'Update school')
```

In controller

```
public function create()
{
    return view('/school/form');
}

public function edit(School $school)
{
    return view('/school/form', ['school' => $school]);
}
```

**Edit:**
try this

```
@php
    $title = isset($school) ? 'Create school' : 'Update school';
    // or other logic
@endphp
@section('title', $title)
```

Comment: Hi. It does not change anything with you suggestion. It seems that it is the condition inside the @section which is not understood.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are actually creating a new school, as you are creating a new instance of school but you are not saving it - hence why the ID is the unique generated UUID and it hasn't been overwritten with 'new'.

```
public function create()
{
    $school = new School();
    $school->id = 'new';
    $school->country_id = 'FR';

    $school->save(); // add in this line

    return view('/school/form', ['school' => $school]);
}
```

Do you have a unique identifier for the school? It might be useful to have an actual unique ID rather than 'new' - just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what was happening, it was me who confused the views in my IDE. Everything works, whether with a `$scholl->id` to null, to 'new' or other.